# Can overwrite Bootstrap CSS for some elements but not others?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following elements I have applied the Bootstrap `btn` and `default-btn` classes to:

```
<input class="btn btn-default add-to-cart-btn" type="submit" name="addcart" value="Add to Cart" />

<div class="btn btn-default enquire-btn" >Enquire</div>
```

My CSS selectors look like:

```
.add-to-cart-btn, .enquire-btn {
//CSS
}
```

However, only the `add-to-cart-btn` CSS overwrties the Bootstrap CSS.

Would anyone know why this is or if/why Bootstrap has issues with overwriting styles on divs?

Comment: can you add jsfiddle demo here as it will help understand more whats conflicting the CSS

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS must be more  specific than the css you are trying to overload.
Your are doing .add-to-cart-btn, .enquire-btn.
So bootstrap might be doing "div.enquire-btn". This is more specific than your CSS.
To overload it div.enquire-btn.

Answer (score 0):

I would try making two different classes.

```
.add-to-cart-btn {...}

.enquire-btn {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that for your input class you've spelt "btn-default" incorrectly. So the bootstrap.css for that class isn't being used, which is why your custom code is working for that and not the other.

Without seeing the rest of your document, I can only assume that your custom css is being loaded before the bootstrap stylesheet which is why that is receiving preference. Try making your custom selectors more specific by adding the btn class to them.

eg;

```
.btn.add-to-cart-btn, .btn.enquire-btn {
  //CSS
}
```

Comment: Oops that was just me re-writing the code here. Its spelt correctly. I have adjusted. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite strange. But I will try to do this instead to see if it's working or not.

```
input.add-to-cart-btn, div.enquire-btn {
  /* Your Style Here */
}
```